# Reusing built-in array methods - JS - Confused

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

This is a piece of code that I couldn't reason about.
These prototype array methods are used on **elems** object but I can't understand why **length** is affected by it. There is no array that has been defined whatsoever. Yet each add operation (via gather method) increments the 'length'. How does this object behave like an array ? Where are all these values stored in ? Can someone please shed some light on this ?

```js
const elems = {
  length: 0,

  add: function(elem) {
    Array.prototype.push.call(this, elem);
  },
  gather: function(id) {
    this.add(document.getElementById(id))
  },
  find: function(callback) {
    return Array.prototype.find.call(this, callback);
  },
}

elems.gather('first');
console.log(elems.length === 1);

elems.gather('second');
console.log(elems.length === 2);

const found = elems.find((elem) => elem.id === 'second');
console.log(found.id === 'second');
```

```html
<h1 id='first'>Hello</h1>
<h1 id='second'>Stack!</h1>
```

Comment: `length`  property is changed because `this` is passed to the `.call()` method.

Comment: _"Where are all these values stored in ?"_ - they are stored on the `elem` object where key is the index and value is the html string; try logging the `elem` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the native `.push` method [explicitly](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.push) takes the [length](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-lengthofarraylike) of the array-like object that it's called on, adds one to it, and assigns that result to the new `.length` property:

```
1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
2. Let len be ? LengthOfArrayLike(O).
3. Let argCount be the number of elements in items.
4. If len + argCount > 253 - 1, throw a TypeError exception.
5. For each element E of items, do
a. Perform ? Set(O, ! ToString((len)), E, true).
b. Set len to len + 1.
6. Perform ? Set(O, "length", (len), true).
```

> Where are all these values stored in ?

On the `length` property of the object. It's not a hidden internal slot.

Comment: _"On the length property of the object"_ - I think OP meant to ask where the values passed to the `gather` function, i.e. `'first'` and `'second'` are stored?